# Detect window closing event in Gecko based browser

Tags: javascript, gecko

How to detect window closing event when user press Alt+F4 or using javascript window.close()  in Gecko based browsers?

Comment: onunload and onbeforeunload  is getting fired when new page is loaded, but I was looking for a technique to detect the browser window closing.

Comment: The close event was not firing in FF or other browsers, but mine was a XUL application. In that the window element support close event and it worked like a charm whenever user press Alt+F4

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload =function(){return '';}
```

Comment: I think, it will 'onbeforeunload' fire when a new page get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

.......

```
window.onunload = function(){
   alert('I am getting closed !!');
};
```

Comment: I think, it will 'onunload ' fire when a new page get loaded